# Stored procedure not taking input parameter in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have created a stored procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `Test_Procedure`(IN INTERNAL_TRANSACTION_ID varchar(50))
BEGIN
    SET @@session.sql_notes = 0;
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tivobatch.temp;
    create TEMPORARY table tivobatch.temp engine=memory AS
    SELECT INTERNAL_TRANSACTION_ID FROM CONTENT_WORKFLOW_STAGING WHERE 
    INTERNAL_TRANSACTION_ID = INTERNAL_TRANSACTION_ID;
    SELECT * FROM tivobatch.temp;
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tivobatch.temp;
    SET @@session.sql_notes = 1;
END
```

I am calling my stored procedure like this:

```
CALL Test_Procedure('74850c0f-4f2c-4894-aa1f-148078f84db0');
```

My input parameter is not picking up. So temp table is created with all the records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mistake i made was,

```
SELECT INTERNAL_TRANSACTION_ID FROM CONTENT_WORKFLOW_STAGING WHERE INTERNAL_TRANSACTION_ID = INTERNAL_TRANSACTION_ID;
```

I added tablename.INTERNAL_TRANSACTION_ID  in my WHERE CLAUSE.

AS

```
SELECT INTERNAL_TRANSACTION_ID FROM CONTENT_WORKFLOW_STAGING WHERE CONTENT_WORKFLOW_STAGING .INTERNAL_TRANSACTION_ID = INTERNAL_TRANSACTION_ID;
```